# Swift - Connecting Contentful Data via multiple Classes

Tags: ios, swift, contentful

I'm trying to get my data from `Contentful` in my `Swift` app but stuck on getting a `dictionary`.

**UPDATE**: The type is Link & linkType is Entry. So I need to decode a link to an entry.

So within my contentful data for `Item A` I have:

```
        "itemB": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Entry",
            "id": "id_is_here"
          }
        },
```

But in my code my `itemB` is `nil`.

Here's what I have tried:

```
// Item A
class ItemA: EntryDecodable, FieldKeysQueryable {

    static let contentTypeId: String = "ItemA"

    // FlatResource Memberes.
    let id: String
    var updatedAt: Date?
    var createdAt: Date?
    var localeCode: String?

    var itemB: ItemB?

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let sys          = try decoder.sys()
        id               = sys.id
        localeCode       = sys.locale
        updatedAt        = sys.updatedAt
        createdAt        = sys.createdAt

        let fields       = try decoder.contentfulFieldsContainer(keyedBy: FieldKeys.self)

        try fields.resolveLink(forKey: .itemB, decoder: decoder) { [weak self] item in
            self?.itemB = item as? ItemB
        }
    }

    enum FieldKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case itemB
    }

    public init(sys: Sys, itemB: ItemB?) {

        id               = sys.id
        localeCode       = sys.locale
        updatedAt        = sys.updatedAt
        createdAt        = sys.createdAt
        self.itemB       = itemB
    }
}

// Item B
class ItemB: EntryDecodable, FieldKeysQueryable {

    static let contentTypeId: String = "ItemB"

    // FlatResource Memberes.
    let id: String
    var updatedAt: Date?
    var createdAt: Date?
    var localeCode: String?

    let name: String?

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let sys          = try decoder.sys()
        id               = sys.id
        localeCode       = sys.locale
        updatedAt        = sys.updatedAt
        createdAt        = sys.createdAt

        let fields       = try decoder.contentfulFieldsContainer(keyedBy: FieldKeys.self)

        self.name        = try fields.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }

    enum FieldKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case name
    }

    public init(sys: Sys, name: String) {

        id          = sys.id
        localeCode  = sys.locale
        updatedAt   = sys.updatedAt
        createdAt   = sys.createdAt
        self.name   = name
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your json itemB doesn't have name or createdAt, why do you want them and you discard type, linkType..? Just trying to check if you missed something or if that is your intention for some reasons

Comment: I may not be using the right terminology, but I think I'm just trying to map to my ItemB from ItemA. So basically, Item A may or may not contain one or more of Item B. And within Item B it has more data.

Comment: @matt I am using Postman and can spit out my JSON so I see exactly what I need. I just don't know the right way to code to get it. I just need to be able to get my itemB (as listed above), so I can get that ID and then do another match against that. But right now Xcode just says it's nil.